# Azure Cloud shell to publish Web App using publish profile

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cloud-shell, publish-profiles

The Azure Cloud Shell can not import the *publish profile* (i.e. "MyWebApp.PublishSettings") that can be exported from the overview of the web app in Azure, which can be used in Visual Studio to publish the web app. I am trying to find the commands to execute with the Azure Cloud Shell (`az webapp up ...` perhaps), but it requires me to sign in first, using `az login ...`. For Visual Studio the *publish profile* file is enough and no login is required. How can I publish like Visual Studio does using the *publish profile*, but using the Azure Cloud Shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to find the commands to execute with the Azure Cloud Shell (`az webapp up` ... perhaps), but it requires me to sign in first, using `az login ...`

When you using the azure cloud shell, it automatically uses the account which logged in the azure portal, so no need to login with `az login` again, just use the command `az webapp up` directly. And you should note, the command [`az webapp up`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_up) is required to run from the folder where the code is present, so you may need to upload your code to the cloud shell first(I have not tested it, not sure if it works in the cloud shell.)

[image]

**Actually**, if you want to deploy the webapp using publish profile, the easiest way I recommend is to [use the kudu api via powershell](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#sample-of-using-rest-api-with-powershell) in local, just open a powershell session in local and run the commands below, you can find the `$password` in the publish profile.

```
$username = "`$webappname"
$password = "xxxxxxx"
# Note that the $username here should look like `SomeUserName`, and **not** `SomeSite\SomeUserName`
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))
$userAgent = "powershell/1.0"

$apiUrl = "https://joywebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy"
$filePath = "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\testdep.zip"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method POST -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```